# django-rest-auth password reset sending wrong domain in email

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I'm trying to test my password reset configuration on my localhost using django-rest-auth. The email verification and registration work, and I can trigger a password reset event and send an email, but the email contains the wrong domain. Right now it is passing a link containing `my-site.com` as the domain instead of `0.0.0.0:8000` as the domain. I am running the app inside a docker container which is why it is `0.0.0.0:8000` instead of `127.0.0.1:8000`.

Current result:

```
You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at My Site.

Please go to the following page and choose a new password:

http://my-site.com/auth/password-reset/confirm/OA/55d-7dc2614593146ac3ce82/

Your username, in case you've forgotten: testaccount

Thanks for using our site!

The My Site team
```

Expected result

```
You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at My Site.

Please go to the following page and choose a new password:

http://0.0.0.0:8000/auth/password-reset/confirm/OA/55d-7dc2614593146ac3ce82/

Your username, in case you've forgotten: testaccount

Thanks for using our site!

The My Site team
```

My url file for my registration is:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from allauth.account.views import ConfirmEmailView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('registration/account-email-verification-sent/', views.null_view, name='account_email_verification_sent'),
    path('registration/account-confirm-email/<key>', ConfirmEmailView.as_view(), name='account_confirm_email'),
    path('registration/complete/', views.complete_view, name='account_confirm_complete'),
    path('password-reset/confirm/(<uidb64>/<token>/', views.null_view, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
]
```

I ran across another post that suggested changing the site id, but I'm not sure this is correct.

How do I get it to pass the currently served domain instead of the site id domain?

Comment: Where is your `PasswordResetView` class? Where its defined in your urls.py?

Comment: Isn't that included in the `django-allauth` views? I have `allauth.urls` included with my `accounts/` url that triggers when the password reset happens, or at least I think it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Easy Solution

**Step 1:** Go to **`/admin/sites/site/`**, You'll see something similar as below,
[image]

**Step 2:** Edit the existing entry with following value **then save it**
Domain name: **0.0.0.0:8000**
Display name: **Your Site Name**
[image]

Comment: I added the site, but it's still redirecting to the first site, not the one I just added.

Comment: Added or Edited?

Comment: I just added 0.0.0.0:8000, but the url sent by the password reset is still pointing to `my-site.com`.

Comment: What is the the value of id/pk of the newly added *site* instance?

Comment: It's 2. Is that what the SITE_ID setting is for?

Comment: Yeah...  Change the **`SITE_ID=2`** in settings

Comment: The thing is, Django using the **`SITE_ID`** value in password reset template