# Django Password Reset Email sending incorrect link

Tags: django, email, return, reset-password

I am using the auth_views login and password reset system for the accounts app in a Django project.
The password reset functionality works fine on the localhost.  However once deployed when trying to reset the password the email that is sent to the user's registered email account contains the incorrect reset URL.  The domain part of the reset URL contains the localhost address and not the domain of the site.

The email is sent to a link like [http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/reset/MTk/azifmz-484db716de96c7628427b41e587c1910/[![enter](http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/reset/MTk/azifmz-484db716de96c7628427b41e587c1910/%5B!%5Benter) image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH5fL.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH5fL.png)

What I am expecting is for the sent email to contain the correct return URL specific to the domain that is sending it. e.g
https://www.example.com/accounts/reset/MTk/azifmz-484db716de96c7628427b41e587c1910.

In settings.py

```
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    }
}
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST= 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER= 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD= 'mypassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS= True
EMAIL_PORT= 587
```

In my accounts urls.py I am using the default classed bassed views provided by django.contrib.auth.  There are no custom views for the reset workflow. I am hoping to configure this workflow to avoid having to write custom views for now.
urls.py

```
path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name="accounts/password_reset_form.html", success_url="done/"), name="password_reset"),
path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
        template_name = "accounts/password_reset_done.html"), name="password_reset_done"),

path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
        template_name = "accounts/password_reset_confirm.html"), name="password_reset_confirm"),
path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
        template_name = "accounts/password_reset_complete.html"), name="password_reset_complete"),
```

Finally the html template is also pretty standard :

```
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% bootstrap_form form %}
      <input type="submit" class='btn btn-primary' value="Reset Password">
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django-rest-auth password reset sending wrong domain in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622267/django-rest-auth-password-reset-sending-wrong-domain-in-email)

Answer (score 2):

Solved - Basically, there were three sites registered in my admin:
pk1 = 127.0.0.0:8000, pk2 = example.com, and pk3= mydomain.com. Just make sure the first one, or better still the only one, in production is the domain you want.

Answer (score 1):

How are you deploying your site. If you use Ngnix as a reverse proxy, your request is now from your own server (127.0.0.1) and not your domain name. You can add the next line to your Nginx-config file:

```
proxy_set_header Host yourdomain.com;
```

This will send your domain in the request

Comment: Thanks, I have deployed it via pythonanywhere.com there is no reverse proxy I create virtual env on host and configure wsgi